# Construct a graph $G$ with connectivity $\kappa(G) =1$ and edge connectivity $\kappa'(G) = N$, where $N$ is any positive integer.

Tags: graph-theory

My first thought was to have a graph that contains a cut vertex $v$ with degree $N$. Where each of the subgraphs formed by removing $v$ is strongly connected within itself. However, this seems incorrect since removing connections to just one of the subgraphs will disconnect the graph making the edge connectivity less than $N$.

My second approach was to put $N$ vertices in one of the subgraphs and $M$ vertices in the other where $M\geq N$. Here, the edge connectivity will be $N$ and the connectivity will be $1$.

I think that my second approach seems correct. I would really appreciate if someone could verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I don't understand your second approach, so I can't say whether it's correct or not.

This is the approach that exists.
Take two complete graphs $P=K_{N+1}$ and $Q=K_{N+1}$ without common vertices.
Now construct graph $G$: $V(G)=V(P)\cup V(Q)$ and
$$
E(G)=E(P)\cup E(Q)\cup\{xv\mid v\in V(Q),v\neq y\},
$$
where $x\in V(P)$ and $y\in V(Q)$ are fixed vertices.

Try to calculate vertex connectivity and edge connectivity of graph $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This gave me the results I was looking for. My second approach was to have two complete graphs with the minimum vertices in either being N and then adding a vertex that connects to each of the vertices in both graphs. So the degree of the cut vertex is 2N and when you remove N edges connecting it to the smaller subgraph, we disconnect the graph. for the vertices in the smaller graph we still need to remove at least N edges from one vertex.